# Search Replace Sed using wild card

Tags: bash, scripting, git-bash

Hello I'm sort of new to scripting and have the following problem

I need to replace 20069.1216.0

`HintPath..\packages\String.20069.1216.0\lib\net\Thoo.Tkc.dll/HintPath`

This works fine at replacing 20069.1216.0 with whatever is provided in $2

```
`xargs sed -i 's/String.20.........0/String.'"${2}"'/g'`
```

I need a way for sed to search for `**"String.*\lib\net\"**`where anything in between `**String.**` and `**\lib...**` is wildcard

This what i have tried

`sed -i 's/String.*\/String.'"${2}"'/g'
sed -i 's/String.*\\/String.'"${2}"'/g'
sed -i 's/String.\(.*\)\\/String.'"${2}"'/g'`

Comment: using WinDoze \ everywhere but `Thoo.Tkc.dll/HintPath`. Is that intentional?

Comment: Im using bash to edit files of a program written in .net, that path is a similar path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that you call `sed` inside a function.

So try this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

replace() {
  echo 'HintPath..\packages\String.20069.1216.0\lib\net\Thoo.Tkc.dll/HintPath' |\
  sed "s/String\.[0-9.]*/String\.${2}/"
}

replace dont_care filename
```

**If your path may contain `--SNAPSHOT` this solution should work for you:**

```
#!/bin/bash

replace() {
  echo 'HintPath..\packages\String.20069.1216.0--SNAPSHOT\lib\net\Thoo.Tkc.dll/HintPath' |\
  sed "s/String[0-9.]*\(--SNAPSHOT\)\{0,1\}/String\.${2}/"
}

replace dont_care filename
```

Comment: Hello what if sometimes it looks like this 'String.20069.1216.0--SNAPSHOT' my search needs to include --SNAPSHOT and replace it